# append tuples to a list

Tags: python

How can I append the content of each of the following tuples (ie, elements within the list) to another list which already has 'something' in it?
So, I want to append the following to a list (eg: result[]) which isn't empty:

```
l = [('AAAA', 1.11), ('BBB', 2.22), ('CCCC', 3.33)]
```

Obviously, the following doesn't do the thing:

```
for item in l:
    result.append(item)
    print result
```

I want to printout:

```
[something, 'AAAA', 1.11] 
[something, 'BBB', 2.22] 
[something, 'CCCC', 3.33]
```

Comment: Do you want _all_ the tuples to be appended to the list, one after another? Or only one at a time? In other words, are you looking for one list containing `[something, tuple1, tuple2, tuple3]`, or several lists, `[something, tuple1]`, `[something, tuple2]`, and `[something, tuple3]`?

Comment: The title is misleading, since based just on the title the answer would be `result.extend(item)` instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
result.extend(item)
```

Comment: Nifty, didn't know `extend` would just handle the tuple the right way.

Comment: @John: `list.extend()` takes any iterable.

Comment: would `result += item` work, as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert a tuple to a list easily:

```
>>> t = ('AAA', 1.11)
>>> list(t)
['AAAA', 1.11]
```

And then you can concatenate lists with `extend`:

```
>>> t = ('AAA', 1.11)
>>> result = ['something']
>>> result.extend(list(t))
['something', 'AAA', 1.11])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the inbuilt [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) function to convert a tuple to a list. So an easier version is:

```
l = [('AAAA', 1.11), ('BBB', 2.22), ('CCCC', 3.33)]
result = [list(t) for t in l]
print result
```

Output:

```
[['AAAA', 1.1100000000000001],
 ['BBB', 2.2200000000000002],
 ['CCCC', 3.3300000000000001]]
```

Comment: why do I get: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable?

Comment: @DGT no idea. what version of python are you using? The above is fine in 2.6/2.7.

Comment: @DGT: You're probably omitting a comma following a tuple.  Something like (a, b, c) (d, e, f) will produce that error. The fixed version would be (a, b, c), (d, e, f)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to unpack the tuple to append its individual elements. Like this:

```
l = [('AAAA', 1.11), ('BBB', 2.22), ('CCCC', 3.33)]

for each_tuple in l:
  result = ['something']
  for each_item in each_tuple:
    result.append(each_item)
    print result
```

You will get this:

```
['something', 'AAAA', 1.1100000000000001]
['something', 'BBB', 2.2200000000000002]
['something', 'CCCC', 3.3300000000000001]
```

You will need to do some processing on the numerical values so that they display correctly, but that would be another question.

Comment: No, not this. But this is the only guy who at least managed to read the question till the end.