# How to put the element of a list to another list directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several dictionaries( `Class1 , Class2`) , and one element of the dictionary stores a list (`Score`) , I want to put the element of the list into another list , but not the list itself to another list .

I try the following code

```
All = []
Class1 = {"name":"A","score":[60,70,80]}
Class2 = {"naem":"B","score":[70,80,90]}
All.append(Class1['score'])
All.append(Class2['score'])
print(All)
```

but the result is

```
[[60, 70, 80], [70, 80, 90]]
```

but what I want is

```
[60, 70, 80, 70, 80, 90]
```

I try this solution below , but I want to know does there exists better solution?

```
All = []
Class1 = {"name":"A","score":[60,70,80]}
Class2 = {"naem":"B","score":[70,80,90]}

Scores1 = Class1['score']
Scores2 = Class2['score']

Scores = Scores1 + Scores2
for score in Scores:
    All.append(score)

print(All)
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly does *better* mean for you in this context?

Comment: a better solution means a shorter solution ....

Comment: funny the number of thing so well hidden in the documentation (such as `extend`)

Comment: in your example, just remove the temp variable Score. `All = Scores1 + Scores2` works just as you want it to.

Comment: Why += is slightly better than extend() is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend)

Comment: Let me explain some things
I store many class dictionaries into a list (Dataset) and I want to put into All list so
`for element in Dataset:

   All.extend(element['score'])`
will be best choice of my answer ......

Comment: You can also do: `for element in Dataset: All += element['score']`. It's completely your choice though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `extend`:

> ```
> extend(...)
>
> L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
> ```

```
All = []
Class1 = {"name":"A","score":[60,70,80]}
Class2 = {"naem":"B","score":[70,80,90]}
All.extend(Class1['score'])
All.extend(Class2['score'])
print(All)
```

Answer (score 3):

All.extend(...) will do what you want...

Answer (score 3):

```
All = Class1["score"] + Class2["score"]
```

To add more elements later:

```
ALL += Classx["score"]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `All.append(Class1['score'])`, the list contained in your dictionnary is treated as a single element and added to your `All` list as a whole.

You either have to loop through each item in the list, as you did, or use the `list.extend` method, which will merge your list with another iterator, ie append every item from that other iterator to your starting list.

Answer (score 3):

If `All` might already contain elements:

```
All.extend(Class1["score"] + Class2["score"])
```