# Python: Append values to list without for-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I append values to a list without using the for-loop?

I want to avoid using the loop in this fragment of code:

```
count = []
for i in range(0, 6):
    print "Adding %d to the list." % i
    count.append(i)
```

The result must be:

```
count = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I tried different ways, but I can't manage to do it.

Comment: Do you understand that `range(0,6)` itself returns a `list`?

Comment: indentation is broken in your code

Comment: and `range(0, 6)` == `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` itself: do `count = range(0, 6)`

Comment: Provide more information about you problem, some test cases maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Range:

since `range` returns a list you can simply do

```
>>> count = range(0,6)
>>> count
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Other ways to avoid loops ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)):

### **Extend:**

```
>>> count = [1,2,3]
>>> count.extend([4,5,6])
>>> count
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Which is equivalent to `count[len(count):len(count)] = [4,5,6]`,

and [functionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653339/645270) the same as `count += [4,5,6]`.

### **Slice:**

```
>>> count = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> count[2:3] = [7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> count
[1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6]
```

(slice of `count` from 2 to 3 is replaced by the contents of the iterable to the right)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`list.extend`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> count = [4,5,6]
>>> count.extend([1,2,3])
>>> count
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the range function:

```
>>> range(0, 6)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

For an answer without `extend`...

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst += [4, 5, 6]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

**List comprehension**

```
>>> g = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> h = []
>>> h
[]
>>> [h.append(value) for value in g]
[None, None, None]
>>> h
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always replace a loop with recursion:

```
def add_to_list(_list, _items):
    if not _items:
        return _list
    _list.append(_items[0])
    return add_to_list(_list, _items[1:])

>>> add_to_list([], range(6))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```