# How do I flatten a list of lists/nested lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python code like this:

```
newlist =[[52, None, None], [129, None, None], [56, None, None], [111, None, None],  
          [22, None, None], [33, None, None], [28, None, None], [52, None, None],  
          [52, None, None], [52, None, None], [129, None, None], [56, None, None],  
          [111, None, None], [22, None, None], [33, None, None], [28, None, None]]
```

I want the `newlist` like:

```
newlist =[52, None, None,129, None, None,56, None, None,111, None, None,22, 
          None, None,33, None, None,28, None, None,52, None, None,52, None,  
          None,52, None, None,129, None, None,56, None, None, 111, None,  
          None,22, None, None,33, None, None,28, None, None]
```

Is there any way to work around ?

Answer (score 128):

What you are trying to do is called flattening the list. And according to the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), you are trying to do the right thing. Quoting from that

> Flat is better than nested.

1. So you can use list comprehension like this

   ```
    newlist = [item for items in newlist for item in items]
   ```
2. Or you can use `chain` from `itertools` like this

   ```
    from itertools import chain
    newlist = list(chain(*newlist))
   ```
3. Or you can use `chain.from_iterable`, where unpacking of the list is not necessary

   ```
    from itertools import chain
    newlist = list(chain.from_iterable(newlist))
   ```
4. Using `sum` function

   ```
    newlist = sum(newlist, [])
   ```
5. Using `reduce` function

   ```
    newlist = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, newlist)
   ```
6. Using `operator.add`. This will be faster than the `reduce` with `lambda` version.

   ```
    import operator
    from functools import reduce
    newlist = reduce(operator.add, newlist)
   ```

**Edit:** For the sake of completeness, included the answers found in [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) as well.

I tried to time all of them in **Python 2.7**, like this

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit("[item for items in newlist for item in items]", "from __main__ import newlist"))
print(timeit("sum(newlist, [])", "from __main__ import newlist"))
print(timeit("reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, newlist)", "from __main__ import newlist"))
print(timeit("reduce(add, newlist)", "from __main__ import newlist; from operator import add"))
print(timeit("list(chain(*newlist))", "from __main__ import newlist; from itertools import chain"))
print(timeit("list(chain.from_iterable(newlist))", "from __main__ import newlist; from itertools import chain"))
```

**Output on my machine**

```
2.26074504852
2.45047688484
3.50180387497
2.56596302986
1.78825688362
1.61612296104
```

So, the most efficient way to do this is to use `list(chain.from_iterable(newlist))`, in Python 2.7. Ran the same test in **Python 3.3**

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit("[item for items in newlist for item in items]", "from __main__ import newlist"))
print(timeit("sum(newlist, [])", "from __main__ import newlist"))
print(timeit("reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, newlist)", "from __main__ import newlist; from functools import reduce"))
print(timeit("reduce(add, newlist)", "from __main__ import newlist; from operator import add; from functools import reduce"))
print(timeit("list(chain(*newlist))", "from __main__ import newlist; from itertools import chain"))
print(timeit("list(chain.from_iterable(newlist))", "from __main__ import newlist; from itertools import chain"))
```

**Output on my machine**

```
2.26074504852
2.45047688484
3.50180387497
2.56596302986
1.78825688362
1.61612296104
```

So, be it Python 2.7 or 3.3, use `list(chain.from_iterable(newlist))` to flatten the nested lists.

Comment: Got a question. Why does this work `[i for j in l for i in j]` and this `[i for i in j for j in l]` doesn't?

Comment: @tMJ In the second form, the sublists are being comprehended again, not the individual elements in the sublists. Just break the comprehension and print the values of `i` in both the cases.

Comment: @tMJ: think about the equivalent for loops.  The first is `for j in l: for i in j: newlist.append(i)`, and the second is `for i in j: for j in l: newlist.append(i)`.

Comment: @DSM i thought it that way, equating it to a nested lopp structure, but the issue is that if the outer loop is `for i in j:` j is not initialized yet. So, what do I make of that. Even though the structure `[i for i in j for j in l]` would assign some value to j, IDK as to what it would be.

Comment: @tMJ: It wouldn't assign any value to `j`; you'd get a `NameError` if it weren't defined.

Comment: @DSM The code works, `>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> [i for j in l for i in j]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [i for i in j for j in l]
[4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]`

Explain this.

Comment: @tMJ: In Python 2, list comprehensions leak the loop variables.  Try the same thing again, but `del j` between the two, and you'll see `NameError: name 'j' is not defined`.

Comment: @DSM aaah! Okay! But I can't still comprehend the output. Maybe you can help.

Comment: An extremely detailed answer, the best i've seen in a while. +1

Comment: The quoted timings are equal up to the last digit for Python 2.7 and Python 3.3: I suspect that these really come from the same run...

Answer (score 21):

Just the easiest one:

```
newlist = sum(newlist, [])
print newlist
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
newlist = [j for i in newlist for j in i]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
temp = []
for small_list in newlist:
    temp += small_list
newlist = temp
```

This should do it.

Comment: Is this quadratic?  It may be better to use temp.extend(small_list).

Comment: what do you mean by quadratic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend 
It's slightly better to use `+=` than `.extend()`

Comment: Quadratic means O(n^2) time.