# Nested list into list of arguments inside nested list

Tags: python, python-3.6

I need help decomposing a nested list. 
 For example:

```
a=[['we','got],['this','in'],['the','bag','man']]
```

into

```
b=['we','got','this','in','the','bag','man']
```

I've tried list comprehensions but continue getting index error when trying to do

```
x_1=[i[0] for i in a]
x_2=[i[1] for i in a]
```

It returns error i[1] is out of range for the list.

Comment: Hello, this is a commonly asked question on SO and the answer is here: [how to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: and you have a typo - `'got` doesn't have a closing quote

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20112805/701049

Answer (score 2):

Required code of above problem

```
a=[['we','got'],['this','in'],['the','bag','man']]
final=[x for b in a for x in b ]
print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[['we','got'],["this",'in'],['the','bag','man']]
b=[]
for elementList in a:
    for element in elementList:
        b.append(element)

print(b)
```

Comment: See this should work but when I insert it into my code print(b) returns ['w','e','t','h','i','s','t',h','e'] for some reason

Comment: @Dave, please execute it again as I have tested the above code and it is printing: `['we', 'got', 'this', 'in', 'the', 'bag', 'man']`