# how to count() within list index

Tags: python

I have a two dimensional list.

```
[[3, 3, 5],
[3, 2, 8],
[2, 1, 3]]
```

I want to count how many times 3 appears as the first value of each list within this list, preferably without iterating through.

Comment: What do you mean "without iterating the list"? Do you want to avoid for loops and list comprehensions for some reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flatten a list of lists/nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112776/how-do-i-flatten-a-list-of-lists-nested-lists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way without using `for` loop:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 3, arr)))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sum` with a `list` comprehension:

```
print(sum([i[0] == 3 for i in lst]))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: that counts every value but I'm only looking for specific indexes. in this example the correct output would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


lst = [[3, 3, 5],
[3, 2, 8],
[2, 1, 3]]


print (Counter(sublist[0] for sublist in lst)[3])
```

You can use the Counter function. Mention which position you want to look at in sublist, and which key (i.e. integer 3) you want to print the result for.

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Isn't this expensive since we are only interested in a fixed position in each of the elements in the list of lists?

Comment: Certainly, but who knows what the OP wants to make with it after. And if limited to the question, being expansive is not a problem considering the length of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy only:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[3, 3, 5],
[3, 2, 8],
[2, 1, 3]]
b = a[:, 0]
c = np.where(b == 3)
print(c[0].shape[0])
```

Using pandas only:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[3, 3, 5],
[3, 2, 8],
[2, 1, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df[df[0] == 3].shape[0])
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think chain from itertools might be the solution if you don't want to use loops

```
from itertools import chain
t=[[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
new_list = list(chain(*t))
print(new_list)
```

**Output**
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

After this you can just use count function this 'new_list' to check the count of any elements

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is to check the order of the entered number in terms of slicing and comparison.

> *According to **python 3.8***

**Code Syntax**

```
lists = [[3, 3, 5], [3, 2, 8], [2, 1, 3]]
num = int(input("check our number: "))
counter = 0
for each in lists:
    if num == each[0]:
        counter +=1
    
print (f" your {num} occur found: {counter} times ")
```

**Output**

```
check our number: 3
 your 3 occur found: 2 times

[Program finished]
```