# Nested list after making a keras prediction

Tags: python, arrays, keras, classification

I used the following to make predictions from my keras model:

```
# fit the keras model on the dataset
ker_model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=200, verbose=0)    
predictions = ker_model.predict(xtest)
predictions = predictions.astype(int)
predictions.mean()
predictions
```

However, the problem is, is that my predictions are in a nested array list. Meaning it looks as followed:

```
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

How can I either ensure that my prediction is not eventually ending up in such a nested list, or unlist the predictions?

What I want my output to look like is:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Are you asking how to flatten a nested list? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112776/how-do-i-flatten-a-list-of-lists-nested-lists EDIT: From the code, it is not clear what `aout` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use
`predictions =predictions.ravel()`
or
`predictions =predictions.squeeze()`