# Is it possible to flatten list of lists in Ansible?

Tags: list, ansible

Need to flatten the array list FROM

```yaml
[
    [
        [
            "10.11.33.11"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "10.11.88.88"
        ]
    ]
]
```

TO

```yaml
[ "10.11.33.11", "10.11.88.88" ]
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as "How to [manage list variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables)?

Since you have list of lists,

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    LIST: [ [ ['10.11.33.11'] ],[ ['10.11.88.88'] ] ]

  tasks:

  - name: Show LIST flattened
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST | flatten(levels=2) }}"
```

you need need to address the level. Resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show LIST flattened] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - 10.11.33.11
  - 10.11.88.88
```

**Background Information**

- [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/)
- [How do I flatten a list of lists/nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112776/)

if someone may be interested.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps.  I did make it work something like  this                                                         set_fact:
    ip_addresses : "{{ ip_addresses | default([]) }} + [ '{{ item[0] }}' ]"
  with_items: "{{ LIST }}"