# I need to make a list of multiple values stored in an temporary variable in a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, variables

```
marks={"Farah":[20,40,50,33],"Ali":[45,38,24,50],"Sarah":[50,43,44,39]}
print(" " ,list(marks.keys()) , "-\n", list(marks.values()))

for key,value in marks.items():
    for j in marks.values():
        for k in (j):
            print(k)
```

This is my code and i need to make the list of all variables stored in k that are 20,40,50,33,45,38,24,50,50,43,44,39

Comment: you want in result a listwith all these values ?

Comment: i need to make a list of all the marks that are stored in temporary variable "k" inside the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flatten a list of lists/nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112776/how-do-i-flatten-a-list-of-lists-nested-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```py
from itertools import chain

marks={"Farah":[20,40,50,33],"Ali":[45,38,24,50],"Sarah":[50,43,44,39]}

output = list(chain(*marks.values()))
print(output) # [20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50, 50, 43, 44, 39]
```

Note that, on python version below 3.7, the order in the list might be different.

Alternatively, if you need a `for` loop (e.g., because you are doing some other operations) and need to store the temporary values, then you can make an empty list first and then append the value to the list at each iteration:

```py
output = []
for val_list in marks.values():
    for v in val_list:
        print(v)
        output.append(v)

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to make a list inside the loop?

Comment: the alternate option doesn't make a list but gives individual values

Comment: @SherMeen Try running `print(output)` at the end.

Comment: it's giving this output:
20
[20]
40
[20, 40]
50
[20, 40, 50]
33
[20, 40, 50, 33]
45
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45]
38
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38]
24
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24]
50
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50]
50
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50, 50]
43
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50, 50, 43]
44
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50, 50, 43, 44]
39
[20, 40, 50, 33, 45, 38, 24, 50, 50, 43, 44, 39]

Comment: it's not making a simple list

Comment: @SherMeen Put `print(output)` __outside__ the for loop (without any indentation), not inside it.