# flat 2d to 1d array

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a list inside.

Can you please help me - how to change the list of lists to list?

I tried with nd.array reshape(), flatten(), and ravel(), but no luck

Input:

```
['Test', [1, 2]]
```

Expected result:

```
['Test', 1, 2]
```

Comment: [`more_itertools.flatten`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.flatten) is another option.

Comment: `I tried with nd.array reshape(), flatten(), and ravel(), but no luck` what do you mean no luck? What exactly did you try? What happened? Was there an error? Is your starting list a basic Python `list` or is it an `ndarray`? If it's an `ndarray` I assume your `dtype` is `object`, so that you don't get errors trying to store strings and numbers in the same list, right?

Comment: Please add more information. What happened when you tried those numpy solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flatten a list of lists/nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112776/how-do-i-flatten-a-list-of-lists-nested-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is known as `flattening an irregular list`. There are a few ways you can do this -

#### Using list comprehension

```
l = ['Test', [1, 2]]

regular_list = [i if type(i)==list else [i] for i in l]
flatten_list = [i for sublist in regular_list for i in sublist]
flatten_list
```

```
['Test', 1, 2]
```

#### Using nested for loops

```
out = []
for i in l:
    if type(i)==list:
        for j in i:
            out.append(j)
    else:
        out.append(i)
print(out)
```

```
['Test', 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers, depending on context and preference:

For python lists:

```py
flattened_list = [element for sublist in input_list for element in sublist]

# or:

import itertools

flattened_list = itertools.chain(*input_list)
```

Or, if you are using numpy.

```py
flattened_list = list(original_array.flat)

# or, if you need it as a numpy array:

flattened_array = original_array.flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
li = ['Test', [1, 2]]

merged = []
for x in li:
  if not isinstance(x, list):
    merged.append(x)
  else:
    merged.extend(x)

print(merged)
```

Output: ['Test', 1, 2]