# why local variable referenced before assignment if I use += on list, but work well for extend?

Tags: python

```
def test():
    a = [1,2,3]
    def test2():
        a += [4,5]
    test2()
    print a
test()
```

In my thoughts, `a += [4,5]` would be equivalent to `a.extend` cus it is in-place [Concatenating two lists - difference between '+=' and extend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend)

However, use `+=` triggers an error, but `extend` works fine.

Am I wrong?

#### Update

I believe I found the reason.

`operator.iadd(a, [4,5])` works fine.

So I believe internally `a+=[4,5]` is interpreted as `a = operator.iadd(a, [4,5])`, and here comes the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of an assignment to `a` (such as `a += [4,5]`) in `test2` causes Python to create an `a` variable local to `test2`, which is never initialized. In Python 3, you would be able to declare `nonlocal a` in `test2` to get around this. In Python 2, you have to use `extend` or workarounds where you put `a` in a 1-element list and use

```
a[0] += [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value):

> This is because when you make an **assignment** to a variable in a scope,
>   that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly
>   named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo
>   assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local
>   variable.

And according to [Augmented assignment statements](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal
>   assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression
>   list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment
>   on the two operands, and **assigns** the result to the original target.

Comment: @colinfang, augmented assignment involves LOAD, **STORE** operation beside the binary operation.