# Python list append and extend - slow speed

Tags: performance, list, python-3.x, append, extend

I've got a list of around 6000 (text) objects, which I am trying to store and pass values from it (after manipulation) to another list.  I am using the `append` and `extend` functions.

The program works fine and gives me the desired result, but it is too slow.

How can I increase its performance (without using С code in my program)?

Comment: Are you certain that these actions are the bottleneck? Have you done any profiling?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653298/8127390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module (included with Python).

This module implements specialized container datatypes providing alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers.

At the top we see:

> [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque): list-like container with fast appends and pops on either end

```
from collections import deque

items = deque([1,2,3])
items.pop()
items.extend()
items.append()
```

Comment: Appending to or popping from the front is a possible reason for slowness, but there is nothing in the question that says that Natasha's code does that.

Comment: you must have missed it, _I am using append and extend functions_

Comment: 'appending to the front' is done with insert(), not append().  extend() is a series of appends to the rear. I see nothing about adding items anywhere other than at the end.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, Natasha seems to have accepted this answer, so it fixed her problem which means you could probably retract your downvote.