# Why do Python lists have an extend method?

Tags: python, list

What does `a_list.extend(list2)` do (or do better) that `a_list += list2` doesn't?

That's all really, except to observe that it would have been an answer if `.extend()` returned the extended list so you could cascade another method. But it doesn't, so you can't.

Comment: `+=` was a) added to the language later and b) for lists is implemented as a `list.extend()` call.

Comment: Ah - hadn't thought about the history. Thanks. Am I right to think that `a_list = a_list + list2` would cause a copy of the list to be made, so relatively inefficient? Also why the downvotes?

Comment: Yes, concatenation creates a new list object.

Comment: More on these two ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend

Comment: `a_list = a_list + list2` creates a new list and binds that to the name `a_list`, replacing the original list object. OTOH, `a_list[:] = a_list + list2` copies the new list back to the original list object that's bound to the `a_list` name. This can be useful if other objects hold references to `a_list` and you want them to reflect any changes that you make to `a_list`, however this is a little slower than the simple `a_list = a_list + list2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`list.extend()` is an *expression* and can be embedded in larger expressions. `+=` (augmented assignment) is a *statement*, and statements can never be embedded in expressions.

So you can do this:

```
doubled_extender = lambda l, it: l.extend(v for v in it for _ in range(2))
```

but you can't use `+=` there.

Note that for `list` objects, the [`object.__iadd__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) that `+=` uses, [calls `list.extend()` directly](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/eea674bf7b59) before returning `self`.

Last but not least, [the Augmented Assignments feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) was added to the language later than `list.extend()`.

Answer (score 3):

Another benefit of `.extend` is that you can call it on a global list because that merely mutates the list, whereas `+=` won't work in that context because you can't assign to a global in the local scope.

Demo

```
a_list = ['one']
list2 = ['two', 'three']

def f():
    a_list.extend(list2)

def g():
    a_list += list2

f()
print(a_list)
g()
print(a_list)
```

**output**

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./qtest.py", line 43, in <module>
    g()
  File "./qtest.py", line 39, in g
    a_list += list2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a_list' referenced before assignment
```

However, you *can* use `+=` if you also use slice assignment since that's also a mutation of the original list:

```
a_list = ['one']
list2 = ['two', 'three']

def g():
    a_list[:] += list2

g()
print(a_list)
```

**output**

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: Of course, you can always just add `global a_list` to the function.

Comment: @chepner Well sure, but I try to avoid using the `global` keyword. Of course, changing globals in any fashion is a dubious practice no matter how you do it, and I suppose using the `global` keyword in your function definition alerts the reader to the fact, which I guess is better than doing it "stealthily" with `.extend` or slice assignment, since "Explicit is better than implicit".