# Python: Reading text file and splitting into different lists

Tags: python, list, file, text

I have a text file which contains two lines of text. Each line contains student names separated by a comma.

I'm trying to write a program which will read each line and convert it to a list. My solution seems to make two lists but I don't know how to differentiate between the two as both lists are called "filelist". For example I may need to append to the second list. How would I differentiate between the two?

Or is it possible for it to create completely separate lists with different names? I want the program to be able to handle many lines in the text file ideally.

My code is:

```
    filelist=[]

    with open("students.txt") as students:

            for line in students:

                    filelist.append(line.strip().split(","))


    print(filelist)
```

Comment: Well if you want it to handle an arbitrary  number of lines, then you won't be able to create a different list each time. In that case you will most likely need a nested list.

Comment: Could you show what is in `studentds.txt` exactly?

Comment: Rebecca, Sarah, Matthew, Charlie                                                    Jenny, Matthew, Laura, Nicky

Comment: Sorry, there should be 4 students on the first line and 4 on the second!

Comment: And you want each line in its own separate list?

Comment: Ideally yes, but I want it to handle if I were to add a third or fourth line in the future too which is why I used the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
text = open("file.txt")

lines = text.split("\n")
entries = []
for line in lines:
    entries.append(line.split(","))
```

If your file is

```
John,Doe
John,Smith
```

then entries will be:

```
[["John", "Doe"], ["John", "Smith"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, how then would I differentiate between the lists should I wish to append to either one?

Comment: Isn't this answer doing exactly what the code in the question already does?

Comment: @Computing102 simply use list indexes. If you want the list of names for say, line 5. Just say `for name in entires[5]:`.

Comment: @Computing102: `entries` is only one list, that happens to be made of two other lists. You can access its elements like with any other list: `entries[0]` will return `["John", "Doe"]` and `entries[1]` will return `["John", "Smith"]`.

Comment: @Computing102 if this answer solved, or _helped_ solved your problem, then consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, filelist will be considered as a list of list because you append a list to it, not an element,
consider doing `filelist += line.strip().split(",")` which will concatenate the lists

Comment: Why not just use `filelist.extend()`?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry pretty much the same as mentioned there: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend)

Answer (score 0):

two lines to done

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    qlist = map(lambda x:x.strip().split(","), f.readlines())
```

or

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    qlist = [i.strip().split(",") for i in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a list for each line, you can use a dictionary where the key is the line number and the value of the dictionary entry is the list of names for that line. Something like this

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    students = {k:line[:-1].split(',') for k,line in enumerate(fin)}

print students
```

The line[:-1] is to get rid off the carriage return at the end of each line