# How to use list slicing to append to end of list in python?

Tags: python, list, slice

Following can be used to add a slice to append to front of list.

```
>>> a = [5,6]
>>> a[0:0] = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1,2,3,5,6]
```

what slice to use to append to the end of list.

Comment: Examples of replacing `list` methods with slicing are [given in the tutorial for many methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use slice, you can use the length of a:

```
a = [5, 6]
a[len(a):] = [1, 2, 3]
a
```

#### output:

```
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

But the simplest is to directly extend `a`:

```
a = [5, 6]
a += [1, 2, 3]   # or a.extend([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: But isn't the slice method faster compared to +=

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar: The `+=` is basically guaranteed to be faster (slicing operations involve temporary `list` objects, and the surprisingly expensive `len` call). `+=` is more readable, and the fastest option available.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Although if it's a non-local variable `extend()` is probably better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261311/499581

Comment: @l'L'l: True, though on Py3, you can explicitly declare the variable `nonlocal` and `+=` will work. Cases where it still won't work include when the `list` in question is part of a `tuple`; `mytuple = ([], []); mytuple[0] += [1,2,3]` is an error, while calling `extend` is fine (because it doesn't attempt to reassign `mytuple[0]`).

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider `extend()`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> Both `+` and `+=` operators are defined for list, which are semantically
>   similar to extend.
>
> `list + list2` creates a third list in memory, so you can return the
>   result of it, but it requires that the second iterable be a list.
>
> `list += list2` modifies the list in-place (it is the in-place operator,
>   and lists are mutable objects, as we've seen) so it does not create a
>   new list. It also works like extend, in that the second iterable can
>   be any kind of iterable.

**Time Complexity**

- Append has constant time complexity, `O(1)`.
- Extend has time complexity, `O(k)`.

> Iterating through the multiple calls to append adds to the complexity,
>   making it equivalent to that of extend, and since extend's iteration
>   is implemented in C, it will always be faster if you intend to append
>   successive items from an iterable onto a list.

↳ [More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/499581)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[len(a):] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

or

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a += [4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got short answer from Jeevaa and Reblochon Masque but if you want to use for loop then try this:

```
a = [5,6]
b = [1,2,3]
for val in b[::-1]:#Reverse b and insert it to a
   a.insert(0,val)
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[1,2,3,5,6]
```