# NameError from modifying global variable

Tags: python-3.x

This is an attempt to make a number increase when a button is clicked.

```
def something():
  CP = 0
  counter = StringVar()
  counter.set("0")
  def click():
    global CP
    global counter
    CP = CP + 1
    counter.set(str(CP))
  label5=Label(window, textvariable=counter, font=("Georgia", 16), fg="blue")
  button5=Button(window, text='Make a Clip', command=click)
  label5.pack()
  button5.pack()
```

There is a name error on line 6 of this section.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36\Paperclips.py", line 14, in click
  CP = CP + 1
NameError: name 'CP' is not defined
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `CP` and `counter` are not `global` they are `nonlocal`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CP` is not a `global` but is a `nonlocal`. Just replace `global` by `nonlocal` so the variable is found in the embedding function.

There's a subtle difference with `counter`. You don't need to do that for the other variable `counter` since you're just using the reference (it's different with `+=`).

Simple standalone example:

```
def a():
    x = 0
    def b():
        nonlocal x  # tell python that x is in the function(s) above
        x += 1
    b()
    print(x)

a()
```

prints `1`

fun difference when using `+=` or `append` with lists:

```
def a():
    l = []
    def b():
        l.append(435)
    b()
    print(l)

a()
```

that works, now:

```
def a():
    l = []
    def b():
        # nonlocal l   # uncomment for it to work
        l += [435]
    b()
    print(l)

a()
```

this should be equivalent, but with `+=` `l` needs to be "declared" as `nonlocal` (more here: [Concatenating two lists - difference between '+=' and extend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend) and the relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261311/6451573)

For integers, though, `+=` cannot be replaced by a function call BTW because of integers immutability. So `nonlocal` remains the sole viable option.