# What's the difference between [a] + [b] and [a].extend([b])?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, addition

There are 2 ways to merge lists together in Python:

1. `['a', 'b', 'c'] + ['x', 'y', 'z']`
2. `['a', 'b', 'c'].extend(['x', 'y', 'z'])`

What's the difference between the 2 methods?

---

What's the more Pythonic way of concatenating more than 2 lists?

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] + [1, 2, 3] + ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

```
gucci_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
gucci_list.extend([1, 2, 3])
gucci_list.extend(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

---

How about combining both?

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].extend([1, 2, 3] + ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: The first creates a new list, while the second modifies the list on the left.

Comment: For starters, the second option makes `new_list` equal `None` (did you try it?) because the function `extend` does not return anything.

Comment: Lots of similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend), and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results), but haven't found a dupe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`['a', 'b', 'c'] + ['x', 'y', 'z']` creates a new list.

`['a', 'b', 'c'].extend(['x', 'y', 'z'])` modifies the first list by adding the second list to it. Since the first list is not referenced by a variable, the resulting list wont be accessible anymore

Answer (score 4):

The first statement creates a new list out of two anonymous lists and stores it in the variable `new_list`:

```
new_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] + ['x', 'y', 'z']
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

The second statement creates an anonymous list `['a','b','c']` and appends another anonymous list to its end (now, the first list is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']`). **However**, the list is still anonymous and cannot be accessed in the future. Since the method `extend` returns nothing, the value of the variable after the assignment is `None`.

```
new_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'].extend(['x', 'y', 'z'])
#None
```

The second statement can be made useful by first naming the list and then altering it:

```
old_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
old_list.extend(['x', 'y', 'z']) # Now, the old list is a new list
```

Answer (score 1):

First one creates a new array from the two.
Second one mutates the original list.