# Python: finding out differences between + and extend from the docs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read this post:
[What's the difference between [a] + [b] and [a].extend([b])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811937/whats-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-extendb)

It says that in terms of lists "+" between lists creates a new list and extend changes the list which is operated on.

```
[1,2,3] + [4]
```

vs

```
[1,2,3].extend([4])
```

Is there any way to get this information without diving into the documentation, but only using the interpreter using help() or dir() for example?

Comment: Your question is very meta. You are better off looking at the online docs... or are you planning to migrate to a place without internet? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting yourself to the interpreter, one way to do it is through the instance method's docstring. You can access it through `help(list.extend)` or through the `__doc__` property. For instance:

```
>>> list.extend.__doc__
'Extend list by appending elements from the iterable.'
```

As for the `+` operator merging two lists, that's only possible thanks to operator overloading by the `list` class. Behind the scenes, it's implemented through a special method called `__add__`. Using the same approach as above:

```
>>> list.__add__.__doc__
'Return self+value.'
```

That being said, the online docs are certainly a less convoluted way to access this information.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're after, but you can easily *check for* or *verify* this behavior from the interpreter.

```py
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4]
>>> l1 + l2, l1, l2
([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [4])
>>> l1.extend(l2), l1, l2
(None, [1,2,3,4], [4])
```

Answer (score 1):

A. If a function (method) modifies data and does not return the result, then is must have mutated objects passed to it as function inputs. This is called in-place modification.

Such functions often deliberately return nothing (None). This convention is nicely described at `list.sort`:

> This method modifies the sequence in place .....
>   To remind users that it operates by side
>   effect, it does not return the sorted sequence

*Note that there exists a technique called "Fluent interface" based on method chaining requiring an opposite approach.*

---

B. you can always check with `id()` if a new object was created

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = ['A','B','C']
>>> id(l1), id(l2), id(l1+l2)
(139855120180552, 139855123390792, 139855123880392)
```