# python build a list recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion

Let's say I have a string

```
S = "qwertyu"
```

And I want to build a list using recursion so the list looks like

```
L = [u, y, t, r, e, w, q]
```

I tried to write code like this:

```
 def rec (S):
    if len(S) > 0:
        return [S[-1]].append(rec(S[0:-1]))
```

Ideally I want to append the last element of a shrinking string until it reaches 0
but all I got as an output is None

I know I'm not doing it right, and I have absolutely no idea what to return when the length of S reaches 0, please show me how I can make this work

(sorry the answer has to use recursion, otherwise it won't bother me)

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many simpler ways than using recursion, but here's one recursive way to do it:

```py
def rec (S):
    if not S:
        return []
    else:
        temp = list(S[-1])
        temp.extend(rec(S[:-1]))
        return temp
```

EDIT:

Notice that the base case ensures that function also works with an empty string. I had to use `temp`, because you cannot return `list(S[-1]).extend(rec(S[:-1]))` due to it being a `NoneType` (it's a method call rather than an object). For the same reason you cannot assign to a variable (hence the two separate lines with `temp`). A workaround would be to use `+` to concatenate the two lists, like suggested in [Aryerez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580744/12062404) (however, I'd suggest against his advice to try to impress people with convoluted one liners):

```py
def rec (S):
    if not S:
        return []
    else:
        return list(S[-1]) + rec(S[:-1])
```

In fact using `+` could be more efficient (although the improvement would most likely be negligible), see answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution:

```
def rec(S):
    if len(S) == 1:
        return S
    return S[-1] + rec(S[:-1])
```

Or in one-line, if you really want to impress someone :)

```
def rec(S):
    return S if len(S) == 1 else S[-1] + rec(S[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `append` mutates the list, this is a bit difficult to express recursively. One way you could do this is by using a separate inner function that passes on the current `L` to the next recursive call.

```
def rec(S):
    def go(S, L):
        if len(S) > 0:
            L.append(S[-1])
            return go(S[0:-1], L)
        else:
            return L
    return go(S, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    L = [i for i in S[::-1]]
```

It should work.

Comment: "the answer *has to use recursion*, otherwise it won't bother me"