# Difference between extend() and + in lists - python

Tags: python, list, concatenation, extend

I want to know what is the exact difference between l1+l2 and l1.extend(l2) as it both concatenates the lists in python.

I have already went through the below post regarding the same question.

[Concatenating two lists - difference between '+=' and extend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend)

I clearly understand that extend() involves a function call and hence can be a bit more expensive. And also l1+l2 option cannot be used for non-local variables.

But in my case, I had a recursive code which eventually returns concatenation of two lists. I used extend method l1.extend(l2). And i got the following errors.

nonetype' object is not iterable

object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

But note that the list is not None or of NoneType.
I even tried printing the type(l1) and len(l1) and the type is list only.

But one thing is that, if i replace extend method with l1 + l2, entire code works fine and i didn't get any error.

May I know why is this so? Any ideas/suggestions

Comment: You clearly know the difference, so go find out why your code is returning a None type at the spot.

Comment: Please add an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) illustrating the same.

Comment: `l1+l2` creates a *new list*, independent of either input list, and returns that.  `l1.extend(l2)` modifies `l1`, and returns nothing.  These aren't even close to being interchangeable pieces of code.

Comment: Thanks jasonharper. Understood that, l1.extend(l2) just modifies the the list but returns None and not the modified l1 list.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> print(l1.extend(l2))
None
```

`l1.extend(l2)` returns none while l1 has been updated. The mistake (but without code we can't tell for sure) is probably that you need to assign `l1.extend(l2)` to a (new) variable again.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. Understood that, l1.extend(l2) just modifies the the list but returns None and not the modified l1 list.. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. The list is updated 'in place'. I made that mistake myself ;-)

Comment: Yeah.. Got it.. Thanks a lot for helping.. :) :)