# python tuples: unpacking into a list using *args

Tags: python, tuples, argument-unpacking

Hello and thanks for your time;

I am using *args to take various arguments, which creates a tuple. How do I 'unpack' a tuple into a list? The following code appends the list with a tuple.

```
grades = []

def add_grades(*args):
    grades.append(args):
    return grades

print(add_grades(99,88,77))
```

I can do this using a for loop and iterating through the tuple, but looking to see if I can unpack directly.

Comment: Could you do `list(args)` ?

Comment: I could, but this just creates a list, whereas I already have a list created and trying to append values.

Comment: Ah, you’re trying to append multiple values, I misunderstood.

Comment: No worries - I had tried that approach as well.

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274095/append-tuples-to-a-list ?

Comment: I didn't think so (I could be wrong?) since I am specifically using *args and trying to append multiple values to an already existing list. But I will review.

Comment: The question is slightly confusing, but the accepted answer is just `list.extend()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `list.extend` method instead:

```
def add_grades(*args):
    grades.extend(args):
    return grades
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert the `tuple` to list you can return `*args` as list and extend the existing list

```
grades = []

def add_grades(*args):
    return [*args]

grades.extend(add_grades(99,88,77))
```

Note that you can extend the list with `tuple` as well

```
def add_grades(*args):
    return args

grades.extend(add_grades(99,88,77))
```

If you don't do anything else in `add_grades` you can also do it without any function

```
grades.extend([99,88,77])
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems that extend() takes any tuple arguments and adds them to a list, which was what I was looking for (and included in the two first answers)